# Can we call a function based on its decorator?

Tags: python

Is there a way to call a function with a specific attribute? I was thinking something like this...

```
def this_one(f):
    return f

class A:
    def a(self):
        print('a')

    @this_one
    def b(self):
        print('b')


class B:
    @this_one
    def c(self):
        print('c')

    def d(self):
        print('d')


def call_this_one(obj):
    obj.this_one()  
    # this obviously won't work due to attribute error, but I was hoping there should be a generic way of
    # referring to functions with this property


call_this_one(A())
```

Comment: Decorators can do _anything you want them to_. This includes adding functions to a registry.

Comment: ...that said, part of what makes this tricky is that these aren't really functions, they're _methods_, so things need to get wired to the object (unless, I suppose, you just want to have your `call_this_one` function search all the methods on an object until you find one that has an attribute that the decorator adds). Now, if you decorated the classes as well, it'd be straightforward enough to add the wiring there -- then that class-decorator could do the search of the functions just once and register its result.

Comment: I don't know python, but I would imagine you just need to instantiate one of the classes and then call the function from the instance.

Comment: @hewiefreeman, the OP is already instantiating the class, that's what makes `A()` different from `A`.

Comment: That last line wasn't there earlier though lol

Answer (score 1):

The method `b` or `c` in your example will be `None` because your decorator function is not returning anything.

The job of a decorator is to return a callable, for example:

```
def decorate(f):
  f._call_me = True
  return f

@decorate
def my_function():
  pass

#my_function._call_me == True
```

That decorator will add a simple custom attribute to the function object.  You could use a technique like this to annotate the function objects and then scan and auto-detect it.  You could also use it to add the function objects to a list or dict and call them from a centralized registry.

Comment: why doesn't that result in an attribute error? if f is a callable and _call_me is not already defined in it?